# indexer from shell not working

Tags: magento-1.7, indexing, indexer, shell

i'm working on a magento CE 1.7.0.2 and I have to update indexes from shell. However I'm trying the commands:

```
php -f indexer.php info
```

and also

```
php -f indexer.php -- -reindex catalog_url
```

but they don't show any output.

UPDATE

If I add -d display_errors=1, it returns:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getSingleton() on a non-object in indexer.php on line 45
```

Any idea why?
thanks so much

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have `shell/indexer.php` from Magento 1.8 or 1.9 but `shell/abstract.php` from Magento 1.7

Since Magento 1.8 line 45 is

```
return $this->_factory->getSingleton($this->_factory->getIndexClassAlias());
```

while in 1.7 it was

```
return Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer');
```

The `_factory` property is instantiated in the constructor of `Mage_Shell_Abstract` and was introduced in Magento 1.8

#### Solution

Restore the original indexer.php file from Magento 1.7. You can get it here:
https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/shell/indexer.php

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're in documentRoot/shell/

The correct syntax would be `php indexer.php --info` (with or without the -f flag depending on your preference).

To re-index you can ommit the `--` and make `reindex` have `--` like this: `php indexer.php --reindex catalog_url`

Take a look at http://www.branded3.com/blogs/re-indexing-magento-command-line/ for more info.

Comment: According to help output, `info` (no longopt!) is absolutely correct. However, the argument parsing does not care at all if you prepend slashes or not. So `-info` and `--info` will lead to the same result.

Comment: it returns same empty output :(